# JUnitParams - executing separate methods before test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junitparams

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class MySimpleTest {

    private MyRec rec;
    private Matrix matrix;

    @Before
    public void createRecognizerBeforeEveryExecution() {
        rec = new MyRec();
        matrix = MatrixUtils.createMatrixWithValues();
    }

    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue1", "input1"},
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue2", "input2"}
        );
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "data")
    public void test1(String output, String input) {
        rec.fun1(matrix);
        assertEquals(output, rec.someFunction(input));
    }

    public static Iterable<Object[]> data2() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{"expectedothervalue1", "input1"},
                new Object[]{"expectedothervalue2", "input2"}
        );
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "data2")
    public void test2(String output, String input) {
        rec.fun1(matrix);
        rec.fun2(matrix);
        assertEquals(output, rec.someFunction(input));
    }

}
```

I'm trying to find out what is the proper way to make this test. I'd like to use parametrized test, because it's really convenient way.

So as you can see, in every test function I call some function (`fun1` and `fun2`). But I need to call it only once per every test (e.g. before each parametrized test execution).

Is there any way to tell JUnitParams that it should execute other function before executing all of parametrized tests?

I can't use `@Before` annotation, because as you can see in `test1` I'm not using `fun2`. It think it should be executed by separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use TestNG to resolve this problem (code just to show my train of thought):

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TempTest {

    private Integer number;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init(Method m) {
        number = 5;
        switch(m.getName()) {
            case "test2":
                fun(10);
                fun2(5);
                break;
            case "test1":
                fun(10);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void fun(int value) {
        number += value;
    }

    public void fun2(int value) {
        number -= value;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(15), number);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(10), number);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(5), number);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

As fun[1|2] does not depend on internal test state, try to place their invocations inside data and data2 methods accordingly.

```
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        rec.fun1(matrix);
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue1", "input1"},
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue2", "input2"}
        );
    }

public static Iterable<Object[]> data2() {
        rec.fun1(matrix);
        rec.fun2(matrix);
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue1", "input1"},
                new Object[]{"expectedvalue2", "input2"}
        );
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

Spliting test cases is not a best practice. Your test are harder to maintain. Flow is far more complicated. There is also a risk your tests start depends on each other. Duplication in tests sometimes is simply better.

PS:
If you are using Strings as test method parameters it's better to pass them exactly like in 25th line of this file:
https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/SamplesOfUsageTest.java instead of special methods.

```
@Test
@Parameters({"AAA,1", "BBB,2"})
public void paramsInAnnotation(String p1, Integer p2) { }
```

Comment: If I correctly understood Solution 2, I shouldn't use parametrized test here, but just produce some duplicated checks in one test method. That is the proper way?

Comment: I assumed you want to remove duplication (fun methods) between test by moving common code to another place (which make them more complicated IMHO). Your @Parameters is good (you want run your test cases on few data sets), but it could be done little simmpler (look PS edit)